# Hough transform detect shorter lines

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, hough-transform, straight-line-detection

Im using opencv hough transform to attempt to detect shapes. The longer lines are all very nicely detected using the HoughLines method.but the shorter lines are completely ignored. 
Is there any way to also detect the shorter lines?

the code I'm using is described on this page 
http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

I'm more interested in lines such as the corner of the house etc. 
which parameter should I modify to do this with Hough transform? or is there a different algorithm I should be looking at

[image: Hough transform with OpenCV python tutorial]

Comment: Have you tried `HoughLinesP()` with the parameter `minLineLength`?

Answer (score 3):

On the link you provide look at [HoughLinesP](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('beach.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 5
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 50, minLineLength, maxLineGap)
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[0]:
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.imwrite('canny5.jpg', edges)
cv2.imwrite('houghlines5.jpg', img)
```

Also look at the edge image generated from Canny.  You should only be able to find lines where lines exist in the edge image.

[image]

and here is the line detection output overlaid on your image:
[image]

Play around with variables `minLineLength` and `maxLineGap` to get a more desirable output.  This method also does not give you the long lines that HoughLines does, but looking at the Canny image, maybe those long lines are not desirable in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, can you provide what values you used as those two parameters in you image?

Comment: @Pita the values you see in the code I posted are the ones that generated the image above.  recall, it's only the green lines as I didn't have the original image.

Comment: Note that your parameters are not what you think they are. Try passing minLineLength and maxLineGap as named parameters to see this. You can see in the documentation that the parameter after threshold is lines, so minLineLength is working as lines (doing nothing) and maxLineGap is working as minLineLength (and, indeed, increasing maxLineGap returns the same lines, filtering out smaller ones).